# Initiate a global variable in a plugin

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a plugin and I'm trying to define an API key and initiate a new class that my other functions can use. I want this to be initiated all the time (even after my plugin is already registered). I tried the following code:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'Mailchimp' ) )
{
    require_once 'src/Mailchimp.php';
}

function init() {
    $apiKey = '1234';
    $api = new Mailchimp( $apiKey );
}
```

However, I have another function later that looks like this:

```
function rb_mailchimp_options() {
     $types = array('user'=>true, 'base'=>true);
     $filters = array('include_inactive'=>true, 'include_drag_and_drop'=>true);
     $templates = $api->templates->getList($filters);
}
```

I'm getting an error message because it's saying `Call to a member function getList() on a non-object` so it doesn't recognize the `$api` variable that I tried to initialize earlier. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read the scoping manual pages http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the API only in that class, store it in a class-variable

```
protected $api;
function init() {
    $apiKey = '1234';
    $this->api = new Mailchimp( $apiKey );
}

function rb_mailchimp_options() {
     $types = array('user'=>true, 'base'=>true);
     $filters = array('include_inactive'=>true, 'include_drag_and_drop'=>true);
     $templates = $this->api->templates->getList($filters);
}
```

See the added `$this->api` to access the class variable in your class.

If you want to use it outside of your class aswell you should create a getter.

**Towards your edit:**

If you don't have these functions in a class but they work together like this you should think about combining them in a class to manage them easier.

If you don't want to do that, th easiest way is to just use the `$api` as a parameter:

```
function init() {
    $apiKey = '1234';
    return new Mailchimp( $apiKey );
}
function rb_mailchimp_options($api) {
     $types = array('user'=>true, 'base'=>true);
     $filters = array('include_inactive'=>true, 'include_drag_and_drop'=>true);
     $templates = $api->templates->getList($filters);
}
```

and than call them like this:

```
$api = init();
rb_mailchimp_options($api);
```

Comment: I don't have a class for my plugin. The class is in a different file that I'm calling. I updated my question. When I add the protected I get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED)`

Comment: I improved my answer and included a way to do it without a class.